# Concatenate charcter cell and hex number in R

Tags: r

I want to concatenate character cell and hex number with an underscore sign
e.g.

```
Input -
Absolute     0x00
True         0x95

Output - 
Absolute_0x00
True_0x95
```

I tried using paste function to concatenate these two cells with underscore as separator,  but it converts the hex number into integer. The problem is - I am still ok if it converts it into 2 integers ONLY. My whole file contains of multiple rows of parameters with these 2 hex numbers, but R instead of converting it into just 2 integers, it is converting into multiple different integer numbers.   Please help
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try using `do.call`:

```
do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep="_"), df)
[1] "Absolute_0x00" "True_0x95"
```

There may be a problem with factors and character strings also. To be sure that numeric conversion will not occur, consider running `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` first or specifying the `colClasses` argument when reading in the data.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("Absolute", "True"), V2 = c("0x00", "0x95"
)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Or just `do.call(paste, c(sep = "_", df))`

Comment: Awesome. It works. Thank you so much. You were right about the character and numbers conversion

Comment: Happy to help. If you feel that it solves the problem consider accepting it as a solution.